# how do I modify php verbs web.config

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi, iis-8.5, web.config

I have a project that needs the `PUT` request enabled for PHP.
By default `GET`, `HEAD`, and `POST` are enabled but I need to enable `PUT` verb from my `web.config`, not from IIS manager.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303041/how-to-enable-delete-put-for-php-app-at-iis or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181966/put-and-delete-on-iis7-php-laravel

Comment: @mkzero I said in web.config

Comment: Have you even read the threads? Because there's a linked thread that pretty much describes exactly that. You don't supply a version or much of any information here, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: @mkzero the linked thread shows how to it in iss manager which I already know how to do. As i said I need to do this in web.config. The version doesn't matter but FYI I'm using the latest version of everything including Windows server 2016

Comment: @mkzero Which one of those is supposed to have an answer to this? Because I couldn't find it in either question, nor could I find it on the 404 page that one of those answers links to.

Comment: @mkzero not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you look in the second thread you'll find a link to another thread in one of the answers, that thread in return has several answers pointing out quite a lot of solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: @mkzero These seem to modify applicationhost.config which I don't want to do. We have to make docs for this project, and telling people how to do it in iss manager is easier If it cant be achieved in web.config. Note: I have very little experience with web.config and it was written by someone else. I can post it if it helps.